# Finding closed form for a product

Tags: closed-form, products

I have no idea how to solve the below product whose closed form I need to solve a problem, can anyone at the very least guide me to a solution or give me a source to check?

$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^k-1}{2^k}$

Comment: Have you calculated the result for small cases like $n = 1, 2, 3$ and seen what you get? Maybe there is a simple pattern you can try to generalize.

Comment: The result is 0 when n≥0, because for the index k=0 we have $2^0-1$ in the numerator. May you have meant for the index to start at k=1?

Comment: Sorry index starts from 1 I edited it. For small cases, the denominator seems very easy but the numerator is what bothers me. It goes 1 3 21 315, I assume there might not be a closed form at all.

Comment: Well, the denominator is clearly just $2^{n(n+1)/2}$. So yes, it's the numerator which seems troublesome.

Comment: A numerical experiment yields an approximate value of 0.288788095088.  This product does converge, but this funky constant brings nothing special to mind.

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A005329) has an entry on the sequence of numerators. It doesn't seem to have any nice formula for it.

Comment: I see thanks a lot.

Comment: @ncmathsadist 0.288 788 095 086 602 421 278 899

Comment: I didn't feel a need to go much further.

Comment: The binary expansion appears in [OEIS A270742](https://oeis.org/A270742). Replacing the minus by plus returns $\,\dfrac 1{1-P}\,$ with $P$ the [Pell constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellConstant.html) (related to dxdydz's answer +1).

Comment: For more information see [OEIS A048651](https://oeis.org/A048651).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to a closed form I can find is in terms of the [q-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html),

$$\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k-1}{2^k} &=\frac{1}{2^{n(n+1)/2}}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(2^k-1 \right ) \\ 
 &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n(n+1)/2}}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-2^k \right ) \\ 
 &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n(n+1)/2}}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-2^{k+1} \right ) \\ 
 &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n(n+1)/2}}(2;\,2)_n.
\end{align*}$$

Or this may be written as

$$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}=\left(\frac{1}{2};\,\frac{1}{2}\right)_n.$$